# Created a Stateful widget and not being able to setstate()

Tags: flutter

Building first flutter app and having some trouble implementing this class

I'm pretty sure its a Stateful Widget, I've created a build method so it should be an implementation of createState() but I'm still getting this error on the name of the class. Because of this error I cant setState() a global list Im adding to.

Error below:

> Missing concrete implementation of 'StatefulWidget.createState'. Try
> implementing the missing method, or make the class abstract.

```html
class TransactionSubmission extends StatefulWidget {

  final controllerForNumPad = NumpadController(format: NumpadFormat.CURRENCY);

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Submit your transaction!"),
        ),
        body: Container(
          //padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
                  child: NumpadText(
                      controller: controllerForNumPad,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50))),
              Expanded(
                  child: Numpad(
                      buttonColor: Colors.blue,
                      controller: controllerForNumPad,
                      buttonTextSize: 35)),
              Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: RaisedButton(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            onPressed: () {
                              //String temp = controllerForNumPad.formattedString;
                              Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) =>
                                          ReportsPage()));
                            },
                            child: Text("Reports",
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25)))),
                    SizedBox(
                        width: 250,
                        child: RaisedButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) => ReportsPage()));
                              ReportsPage._key.currentState
                      .setTodo(Transaction(total: controllerForNumPad.formattedString));
                  setState(() {

                  });
                              controllerForNumPad.clear();
                            },
                            textColor: Colors.white,
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            child:
                                Text("Submit", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25))))
                  ])
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The stateful widget is an abstract class like the stateless widget. In the case of the stateful widget, you have to override the createState method, not the build method. Your build logic should be in the widget state class you return from your `createState` implementation.

Read the flutter [widgets introduction](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets-intro) for more details.